# Hibernation from C# vs Hibernation from close lid - wakeup issue

Tags: c#, windows, wakeup, hibernation

I have a problem with hibernation and wake up events.
When I go into hibernation using C# code

`Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, false);`

everything works fine and computer wakes up on events. The problem is when I just close the lid having hibernation as action. In this case computer never came back and the only way to start it was by pressing the power button.
Of course I could set lid close action to none and always go into hibernation using app but that is not the best solution.

I would like to know what is the difference between these two hibernations. I thought this should be the same but seems it is not. Is there a way to modify hibernation action on lid close to work the same as this one called from C# code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that after hibernation from code when the lid was open computer woke up at scheduled time however with closed lid computer tried to turn on but immediately turned off and no matter if it was hibernated from code or not. I have spot this when my laptop was charging and charge led was on. When I'm turning it on this led switches off for a second and then goes back. The same has happened with closed lid at scheduled time.

It seems that lid state (open/close) is the key here.